# Crontab blocking winston to write to my log files

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, winston

I'm using winston to log all output from my node js app to a log file, but when I run the app as a crontab job, it does not write anything to the log file. This is setup of my winston transport:

```
var winston = require('winston'),
        getTimeStamp = function() {
            return new Date().toString();
    }

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
    winston.add(winston.transports.File, {
            filename: environment.logFileName,
            maxsize: 1024*1024*10, //10MB
            timestamp: getTimeStamp(),
            colorize: true
    });
    winston.remove(winston.transports.Console);
}
 winston.exitOnError = false;
```

Winston seems to work fine if I direct all my output do a cron.log file, like this:

```
0 12 * * 1 /apps/accounting/server/Invoice_Worker/test.sh >> /var/log/cron.log
```

or If I use console.log to do all the output.

I also tried doing this and did not fix the issue:

```
0 12 * * 1 /apps/accounting/server/Invoice_Worker/test.sh >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

winston is not writing to my test or production logs regardless of the environment I run the app in. Any advice would help please. Thanks!

Comment: A lot of the time a question involves "X won't write to file" it has something to do with permissions. I'm not sure how that works with winston or node, but it may be worth checking.

Answer (score 4):

The issue has been solved. I did mistake of not providing absolute paths to my log files inside my node server and crontab always require absolute paths

Comment: lifesaver man, great answer